# Firebase: initialize a tree made of collections

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I built a tree consisting of a set of collections. Each collection is in turn made of other sub-collections and so on.

Every collection has the same field (which is the one I want to update).

Is there a way to update every level of the tree with the same value (in order to initialize it)?

Some images of the tree's structure:[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) to perform multiple individual writes at once, but there is no way to update a field across a collection of documents in a way similar to e.g. an `UPDATE` in SQL databases.

You would need to enumerate each document that needs to be updated and perform an update on each of those documents.